# Adding multiple users to multiple OU's using a single line powershell command

Tags: powershell

I am very new to PowerShell and I have a .csv file that contains 100 different users with the fields Name,Surname,Section and depending on the section the user has to be created in that specific OU. Ex:Joe,Heart,Accounts - When I execute the command I the user has to be created in the Accounts Organizational Unit.

The biggest challenge is that I have to use only a 1 line command to create the 100 users in their respective OU. I tried multiple commands and watched numerous videos but none seem to work. I am working on Windows Server 2012.

Currently, I am trying to make use of this command

```
Import-Csv C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\HomeList.csv  
       | ForEach-Object { Set-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity $_.Section -Member $_.Name }
```

And I am getting the error

> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Member'

Comment: For existing users, you can make use of the `Move-ADObject -Identity $UserDN -TargetPath $OU`. For new users, you can utilize `New-ADUser -Path $OU`. Does Section relate to a specific child OU name where the remaining parent OU paths are identical?

Comment: It "seems" like this command has promise for an existing user: `Move-ADObject -Identity (Get-ADUser $_.Name) -TargetPath $_.Section`. It is difficult to give an exact answer without understanding more about HomeList.csv as it relates to OUs and AD identities.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. As for your question I believe so yes.

Comment: HomeList has 3 columns which are name surname and section. There are 3 different sections lets refere to them as T1 T2 T3 which I created in my AD already. In the list there are around 102 users with different sections which I have to import this csv file and each user that has his Section T1 has to be created in T1 OU. This also applies for all other users that have T2 or T3 as their section. If you want I can provide you with a screenshot tomorrow as I am currently in bed

Comment: The reason I ask these questions is because commands like Move-ADObject and New-ADUser expect user identities and OUs to be passed into them in a certain format. So if your file only contains someone's first name and last name, you will need more parameters set before it will create a user. If you want to put a user into a certain OU, you will need the X.500 path format for the OU target. A folder name only will not be sufficient. Since we know nothing about your environment, we can only guide you rather than give an exact answer with the information provided.

Comment: Why do you have to use a 1 line command?

Comment: This is a school exersice and if I manage to use a single line command I will get more marks

Comment: Wow.. Who is teaching you to do that? One-liners are usually harder to read and update later. Also mistakes are made more easily when cramming everything into on line of code. Writing out code and adding comments to it is a GOOD thing. Especially when learning a language.

Comment: The cmdlet [Set-ADOrganizationalUnit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-adorganizationalunit?view=win10-ps) does not have a parameter called `-Member`. You will need the [Move-ADObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/move-adobject?view=win10-ps) cmdlet for that. Have a close look of what the `-Identity` parameter needs.

Comment: @Theo I know, in fact, our lecturer told us that 1 line code is very hard taking in consideration I never used Powershell. Thank you a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a school exercise I don't think it would be a good thing to give you a working piece of code to simply copy/paste.
I can however give you tips on where to look..

The CSV file has these fields as you say: `Name`, `Surname`, `Section` where

- 'Name'    seems to be the users first name
- 'SurName' is the users last name
- 'Section' is the (display)name of the OU

Each user in the CSV must be moved to the specified OU and for that purpose the ActiveDirectory module has the cmdlet [Move-ADObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/move-adobject?view=win10-ps#required-parameters), so you iterate through the data with a Foreach-Object {...}

There are several issues to deal with here.

The first one is that the `Move-ADObject` cmdlet takes an `-Identity` parameter that can either be a DistinghuishedName or a GUID. You can also pipe an ADUser object to it.
In your CSV you have the users first name (AD property `GivenName`) and the users last name (property `SurName`) and so you will need to get the user **object** from AD first in order to be able to use Move-ADObject.

For that, there are several answers to be found on the internet, both using the `-Filter` aswell as the `-LDAPFilter` parameters of [Get-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps).

The second issue is that `Move-ADObject` needs a `-TargetPath` parameter in the form of a **DistinghuishedName** and since your CSV file only contains the (Display)Name of the target OU, you need to get that first too.
The cmdlet for that is [Get-ADOrganizationalUnit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adorganizationalunit?view=win10-ps) where you can use the `-Filter` parameter, something like this: `-Filter "Name -eq '$($_.Section)'"`

<sup>Note: you can also use `Get-ADObject` and filter on "ObjectClass -eq 'organizationalunit'" as an alternative for `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit`, but that is a bit more difficult.</sup>

Once you have both AD objects, you're all set to use the `Move-ADObject` cmdlet to move the user to the target OU, but always add the `-WhatIf` switch to the command when trying out your code. Only if you are satisfied with the results shown in the console, you can take that switch off.

Please do **not** attempt to put all this in a single line. Write it out and add comments to the code. If you got it working you may want to look at speeding things up a little by organising the data from the CSV using [Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-6)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I will try my best to make this work :)

Comment: @TristanFarruġia Thanks for the feedback. You'll have some looking up to do but I'm sure you can make it work!